# Dockerfile run entrypoint before shell entrypoint

Tags: docker

I'm wanting to do some last minute setup on run before passing arguments to the shell entrypoint, to accomplish this I have the following in mind.

```
ENTRYPOINT ./run_binary ${args}; /bin/sh -c
CMD ./run_binary
```

However, by doing this, it doesn't seem that any `CMD` arguments make it to the shell entrypoint. Is there a way around this? I'm just wanting to run a setup step on a binary before handing back control to the shell entrypoint (and then to the USER via `CMD`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an intermediate build image that triggers an `ONBUILD` statement from your original Dockerfile, see: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/onbuild

> The ONBUILD instruction adds to the image a trigger instruction to be
>   executed at a later time, when the image is used as the base for
>   another build. The trigger will be executed in the context of the
>   downstream build, as if it had been inserted immediately after the
>   FROM instruction in the downstream Dockerfile.
>
> This is useful if you are building an image which will be used as a
>   base to build other images, for example an application build
>   environment or a daemon which may be customized with user-specific
>   configuration.

Regarding CMD and ENTRYPOINT, see: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact

1. Dockerfile should specify at least one of `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`
    commands.
2. `ENTRYPOINT` should be defined when using the container as an
    executable.
3. `CMD` should be used as a way of defining default arguments for an
    `ENTRYPOINT` command or for executing an ad-hoc command in a
    container.
4. `CMD` will be overridden when running the container with alternative
    arguments.

Answer (score 2):

CMD becomes a list of arguments to send to ENTRYPOINT when both are specified, [see the manual](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/cmd), so that's not the way to go

but you could use a .sh script as ENTRYPOINT, that first executes your binary command and then forwards the received arguments to a shell

I haven't tried it but something along the lines of

```
#!/bin/sh

./run_binary
/bin/sh -c "$@"
```